# Android GridView Gallery memory overflow

Tags: android, gridview, memory-leaks, gallery, layout-inflater

sorry I could not find a working solution yet. Well I guess I have found the memory leakage but could not get around it. If I start my Anadroid-App, the android monitor expands to 150 Mb memory in use.

Here is my Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import develop.sb.com.network.FileTransfer;


public class  Gallery extends Activity {

LayoutInflater inflater;
public Context GalCon;
public GridView gv;
public ArrayList<File> list;
public ArrayList<String> UploadFileArray;
public Gallery()
{
    GalCon = this;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

    UploadFileArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    list = imageReader(TextViewAdapter.selectedDir);

    gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gv.setAdapter(new GridAdapter());

    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            /*
                [Position] index, bedeutet das entsprechende Element
            */

            if(view.getPaddingLeft() > 0)
            {
                view.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            // Call the method you need to call on ImageView click event
            else
            {
                view.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), list.get(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            UploadFileArray.add(list.get(position).toString());

            File f = new File(list.get(position).toString());
            System.out.println(f);

        }
    });

}

public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //This may be the memory leakage
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) GalCon.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_grid, parent, false);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        /*Hier wird das Bild eingefügt*/
        iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString()));
        /* iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.d("Image", "Clicked");
                if(v.getPaddingLeft() > 0)
                {
                    v.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                // Call the method you need to call on ImageView click event
                else
                {
                    v.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        });*/

        return convertView;
    }
}

public static ArrayList<File> imageReader(String root)
{
    ArrayList<File> a = new ArrayList<>();

    File verzeichnistogetPic = new File(root);
    File[] files = verzeichnistogetPic.listFiles();
    for(int i = 0; i<files.length; i++)
    {
        if(files[i].isDirectory())
        {
            //  a.addAll( imageReader(files[i]));
        }
        else
        {
            //  if(files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg"))
            //   {
            a.add(files[i]);
            //   }
        }
    }

    return a;
}


public void sendPictures(View view)
{
    if(this.UploadFileArray.size() > 0 ) {
        for (String temp : this.UploadFileArray) {
            FileTransfer.getCameraFile(temp);
        }
    }
}}
```

I am going to get all the files from a directory within the sdcard and gonna create a gallery with touch event. But as I said. I got a memory leakage and if the pictures are too big (2-3Mb) than its gonna crash. I would be glad if you could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the images directly in the imageview, use a image caching library like piccasso, volley or Universal Image lib...!
All of these are cached the image in the memory which results in less memory consumption from the app...!
I personally use Piccasso for that purpose, Here is the library URL,

http://square.github.io/picasso/

And below is the simple tutorial of it,
http://square.github.io/picasso/

**Edit**: Your GridView constructor:

```
private LayoutInflater inflater; //This is your field variable
public GridAdapter()
{
      inflater = (LayoutInflater) GalCon.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Your getView() should be look like below,

```
   @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null){

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_grid, parent, false);
}
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            /*Hier wird das Bild eingefügt*/
            iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(getItem(position).toString()));
            /* iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Log.d("Image", "Clicked");
                    if(v.getPaddingLeft() > 0)
                    {
                        v.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
                        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                    // Call the method you need to call on ImageView click event
                    else
                    {
                        v.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
                        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                }
            });*/

            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: Ah ok, I will give it a try, thank you. Other solutions are still welcome :)

Comment: Tryed: Picasso.with(GalCon).load(new File(getItem(position).toString())).into(iv); But I still got the memory leakage. Also I noticed that getView gets executed a lot of times? Can someone explain me why?

Comment: The problem is, that getView gets executed about 20 times, even when I start the app and no function of Gallery is called?

Comment: There is a very small problem with your getView

Comment: Oh man THANK YOU!!! The one and only thing is, that i had to put the ifnlater into the oncreate method because of the following error message:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate(). Now I got about 20 MB in use and not 120MB! Really thank you sir!